# PHP accessing object generated by other namespace elements

Tags: php, properties, namespaces

I have a class in a namespace which load json files via another class imported from another namespace

```
use *\*\file\json_datas as file;
```

then in a method I load the files by instanciating file class without problem

```
    private function load_json(){

    $this->settings["json"] = new file($this->settings["file"],false,false);

    $this->content["json"] = new file($this->content["file"],false,false);
```

At this point, an output of $this->content["json"] returns me what I expect, or

```
*\*\file\json_datas Object
(
    [file] => en.json
    [name] => en
    [extension] => json
    [folder] => ####
    [fullpath] => /#####/
    [datas] => stdClass Object
        (
            [head] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Array
```

But then my problem occurs when I want to reference to head directly as follow

```
$this->head =& $this->content["json"]->datas->head;
```

neither

```
$this->head =& $this->content["json"]["datas"]["head"];
```

an output of $this->head is blank and (having error_reporting at E_ALL) i get no error/notice logged. Any idea ?

Comment: If the last one didn't throw any errors, or at least notices/warnings, you should make sure that you have the error reporting set to `E_ALL` and then check the web servers error log. You could also enable display errors while developing. At least one of those two code snippets should throw a warning/notice. From the dump you've posted, it should be the last that should fail

Comment: Yes, indeed, as I wrote it if you read the entiere post, my problem occurs right there. error_reporting is defined at E_ALL, and I have no error logged.

Answer (score 0):

I found why.
No problem with the syntax, just the datas property of the file class was defined to private.
I am new here, I don't know if I should leave this thread in case in case it is useful for someone else...